# IoC component registration

Tags: c#

How do you list your referenced solution assemblies for IoC registration? I was really tired of typing something strange as `new [] { typeof(SomeType).Assembly, … }`. What do you think about the following approach?

Use case:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var a in Solution.Assemblies)
            Console.WriteLine(a);            
    }
}
```

Where `Solution.Assemblies` is:

```
public static class Solution 
{
    static IEnumerable<string> AssemblyNames => new[] {
        "ValueCache", "ValueCache.Tests", "LazyProxies", "ConsoleApplication1", "ClassLibrary1"
    };

    public static IEnumerable<Assembly> Assemblies => AssemblyNames
        .Select(an => Load(an))
        .Where(a => a != null);

    [DebuggerHidden]
    static Assembly Load(string assemblyName)
    {
        try
        {
            return Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(assemblyName));
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

… being generated by `Solution.tt` file:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostSpecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDte" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #> 
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #> 
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #> 
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating" #>
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SolutionConfiguration
{
    public static class Solution 
    {
        static IEnumerable<string> AssemblyNames => new[] {
            <#= String.Join(", ", from name in new SolutionAssemblyNames(Host)
                                  select $"\"{name}\"") #>
        };

        public static IEnumerable<Assembly> Assemblies => AssemblyNames
            .Select(an => Load(an))
            .Where(a => a != null);

        [DebuggerHidden]
        static Assembly Load(string assemblyName)
        {
            try
            {
                return Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(assemblyName));
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}

<#+

    class SolutionAssemblyNames : IEnumerable<string>
    {
        public SolutionAssemblyNames(ITextTemplatingEngineHost host)
        {
            Host = host;
        }

        public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator() => Assemblies.GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerable<string> Assemblies => Projects
            .Select(p => p?.Properties?.Item("AssemblyName")?.Value as string)
            .Distinct().Where(a => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a));

        IEnumerable<Project> Projects => VisualStudio.Solution.Projects.OfType<Project>();
        DTE VisualStudio => (Host as IServiceProvider).GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
        ITextTemplatingEngineHost Host { get; }
    }
#>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fascinating solution. I kept looking at it and thinking "There must be an easier way!" but every possible solution I came up with had a fatal flaw.

All I really have, then, is nitpicking:

```
public static IEnumerable<Assembly> Assemblies => AssemblyNames
        .Select(an => Load(an))
```

Can be simplified to:

```
public static IEnumerable<Assembly> Assemblies => AssemblyNames
    .Select(Load)
```

`SolutionAssemblyNames` is looking fairly dense. I'd add 1 line of whitespace between each property to make it a bit more readable.